# Именование файлов с классами по БЭМ

Tags: javascript, html, бэм

Есть БЭМ блок b-rating, для которого есть js класс `Raiting` в файле b-rating.js.

Так же есть javascript класс `RaitingData`. Его хочется вынести из файла b-rating.js, но тогда не понятно как называть такой файл.

Выносить в отдельный блок i-raiting-data выглядит очень избыточно.

`RaitingData` не является ни элементом ни модификатором, и сделать файл типа b-rating__data.js было бы неправильно.

Как следует поступать, когда есть много javascript классов нужных блоку (и по логике лежащих в одном неймспейсе с ним), но непонятно как назвать файл с ними?

Comment: А что далает `RatingData`?

Answer (score 1):

Отдельный файл `i-raiting-data`. Вполне нормальное решение.

Comment: В таком случае эти два файла не будут сгруппированы. Допустим у нас для каждого блока будет по множеству таких файлов. Тогда будет ужасный хаос в папке с блоками.

Comment: Задачу связи между блоками мы решаем с помощью https://ru.bem.info/technology/deps/about/